# Access razor component property from within a JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, razor, blazor

A razor component binds its OnInput event to a JavaScript function.
How can I read the razor component property from within the JavaScript function?

Comment: Show youor code that does the binding - because that's going to be important

Comment: When will people learn how to [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#invoke-an-instance-net-method)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in your Razor component with the [JSInvokable] attribute.
In this method you can return the properties that you need in your Javascript.

```
[JSInvokable]
public static Task<int[]> ReturnArrayAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(this.MyProperty);
}
```

And in javascript side:

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('{ASSEMBLY NAME}', 'ReturnArrayAsync', {ARGUMENTS}); //in that case we do not need arguments
```

It should do the trick.
Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Dylan, but I need a value from a razor component property. It cannot be a static method.